How to perform flann.knnMatch along a horizontal line?
I am trying to find correspondence between a pair of stereo images. However, there are some wrong correspondences, so I am thinking limit the search along the horizontal line since they are stereo images.
Is there a way to do that using OpenCV functon? Or do I have to manually create a list of keypoints along the epipolar line, then do the knnMatch with this list?

[mre] required. do you realize that after the feature matching, there's a RANSAC step or similar model-fit/filter? if you didn't know that, please tell me what teaching materials you use so I can know what they are and then say that they're bad

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
